# Tds automation in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
const q3Msg = document.getElementById('tableq3');

var value = [{
    id: 1, 
    result: 65, 
    situation: 'YES'
}, {
    id: 2, 
    result: 22, 
    situation: 'NO'
}];

function q3Calc() {
    q3Msg.classList.remove('hidden');

    var table = document.createElement('tbody'), tr, td, row, cell;
    for (row = 0; row < value.length; row++) {
        console.log(value);
        tr = document.createElement('tr');
        for (cell = 0; cell < 3; cell++) {
            td = document.createElement('td');
            tr.appendChild(td);
            td.innerHTML = value;
        }
        table.appendChild(tr);
    }
    document.getElementById('tableq3').appendChild(table);
}
```

I have the above code for automate `tds` in html. But I have the below image as a result.

[image]

How can I show each array index in a separate td?

For example, in the first row, I would like show 1 65 YES, and next row 2 22 NO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your porblem is in `td.innerHTML = value;`. Replace it with `td.innerHTML = value[row][Object.keys(value[row])[cell]];` to get expected value.

```js
const q3Msg = document.getElementById('tableq3');

var value = [{
  id: 1,
  result: 65,
  situation: 'YES'
}, {
  id: 2,
  result: 22,
  situation: 'NO'
}];

function q3Calc() {
  q3Msg.classList.remove('hidden');

  var table = document.createElement('tbody'),
    tr, td, row, cell;
  for (row = 0; row < value.length; row++) {
    console.log(value);
    tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (cell = 0; cell < 3; cell++) {
      td = document.createElement('td');
      tr.appendChild(td);
      td.innerHTML = value[row][Object.keys(value[row])[cell]];
    }
    table.appendChild(tr);
  }
  document.getElementById('tableq3').appendChild(table);
}
q3Calc();
```

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="tableq3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problems were that you weren't accessing each element (object in this case) in the array (you never used `row` after assigning it).

Then you never used the keys within each object (you were just calling `value` which means each time you were basically grabbing the entire array each time).

```js
const q3Msg = document.getElementById('tableq3');

var value = [{
    id: 1, 
    result: 65, 
    situation: 'YES'
}, {
    id: 2, 
    result: 22, 
    situation: 'NO'
}];

function q3Calc() {
    q3Msg.classList.remove('hidden');

    var table = document.createElement('tbody'), tr, td, row, cell;
    for (row = 0; row < value.length; row++) {
        console.log(value[row]);
        tr = document.createElement('tr');
        for (let key in value[row]) {
            td = document.createElement('td');
            td.innerHTML = value[row][key];
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
        table.appendChild(tr);
    }
    document.getElementById('tableq3').appendChild(table);
}

q3Calc();
```

```css
td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id='tableq3'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want that?

```js
const q3Msg = document.getElementById('tableq3');

var value = [{
    id: 1, 
    result: 65, 
    situation: 'YES'
}, {
    id: 2, 
    result: 22, 
    situation: 'NO'
}];

function q3Calc() {
    // q3Msg.classList.remove('hidden');

    var table = document.createElement('tbody'), tr, td, row, cell;
    for (row = 0; row < value.length; row++) {
        console.log(value);
        tr = document.createElement('tr');
        for (cell = 0; cell < 3; cell++) {
            td = document.createElement('td');
            tr.appendChild(td);
            td.innerHTML = '['+value[row].id+','+value[row].result+','+value[row].situation+']';
        }
        table.appendChild(tr);
    }
    document.getElementById('tableq3').appendChild(table);
}
q3Calc();
```

```html
<div id="tableq3"></div>
```